# How to cut a number in different bin and expand the data frame with the new bins?

Tags: r, data-binding, cut

I would like to compute something really simple, but I don't find the solution. I want to cut in bins certain numbers, but I want to save the bins.

```
bin.size = 100 
df = data.frame(x =c(300,400), 
                y = c("sca1","sca2"))
cut(df$x, seq(0, 400, bin.size), 
    include.lowest = TRUE)
```

Gives me

```
[1] (200,300] (300,400]
Levels: [0,100] (100,200] (200,300] (300,400]
```

But what I want something like this:

```
        bin    y
1   (0,100] sca1
2 (100,200] sca1
3 (200,300] sca1
4   (0,100] sca2
5 (100,200] sca2
6 (200,300] sca2
7 (300,400] sca2
```

I want to do this because I want to calculate the number of values that enter in bins of 100. For example:

```
df2 = data.frame(snp = c(1,2,10,100,1,2,14,16,399), 
                 sca = c("sca1","sca1","sca1","sca1","sca2","sca2","sca2","sca2","sca2"))
df2
  snp  sca
1   1 sca1
2   2 sca1
3  10 sca1
4 100 sca1
5   1 sca2
6   2 sca2
7  14 sca2
8  16 sca2
9 399 sca2
```

snp could be the the position in a vector sca1.

The end goal is to obtain something like this:

```
        bin    y num
1   (0,100] sca1   4
2 (100,200] sca1   0
3 (200,300] sca1   0
4   (0,100] sca2   4
5 (100,200] sca2   0
6 (200,300] sca2   0
7 (300,400] sca2   1
```

The best I can do is this:

```
df2$cat = cut(df2$snp, seq(0, 400, bin.size), 
include.lowest = TRUE)
df2
  snp  sca       cat
1   1 sca1   [0,100]
2   2 sca1   [0,100]
3  10 sca1   [0,100]
4 100 sca1   [0,100]
5   1 sca2   [0,100]
6   2 sca2   [0,100]
7  14 sca2   [0,100]
8  16 sca2   [0,100]
9 399 sca2 (300,400]
```

Or this:

```
table(df2$cat,df2$sca)
            sca1 sca2
  [0,100]      4    4
  (100,200]    0    0
  (200,300]    0    0
  (300,400]    0    1
```

But the problem with this last attempt is that the category `(300,400]` doesn't make sense for `sca1` because it doesn't exist. It should be `NA` or not appearing. How to solve this?

Comment: Why doesn't `(300,400]` make sense? Given the input `df2` , `(100,200]` and `(200,300]` shouldn't be present either for `sca1`?

Comment: In fact, 0 and NA are not considered the same for my analysis. So I need to change that. But as you might expect, I'm not using these data. This is just a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using a few packages from the `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  left_join(nest(df2, snp, .key = "snp"), by = c("y" = "sca")) %>%
  mutate(
    cuts = map(x, ~ seq(0, ., by = 100)),
    tbls = pmap(
      .l = list(snp, cuts),
      .f = function(xx, breaks) {
        z <- table(cut(xx$snp, breaks))
        data_frame(cut = names(z), count = z)
      }
    )
  ) %>%
  select(y, tbls) %>%
  unnest()
#      y       cut count
# 1 sca1   (0,100]     4
# 2 sca1 (100,200]     0
# 3 sca1 (200,300]     0
# 4 sca2   (0,100]     4
# 5 sca2 (100,200]     0
# 6 sca2 (200,300]     0
# 7 sca2 (300,400]     1
```

Comment: I have a difficulties understanding what's going on there. If I have this dataset instead and want to calculate the mean of r2 instead of the number of snp per category (count), what would I need to change?  `df2 = data.frame(snp = c(1,2,10,100,1,2,14,16,399), 
                 r2 = c(0.7,0.8,0.7,0.1,0.9,0.98,0.8,0.8,0.01),
                 sca = c("sca1","sca1","sca1","sca1","sca2","sca2","sca2","sca2","sca2"))`. Thanks! I thought it would be simpler!

Comment: if you run just the top two lines of the code (i.e., `df %>% left_join(...)`) with the first `df2` and compare with your new `df2`, you will see that the variable `r2` is completely upsetting the grouping. Stepping through the code pipeline like this is helpful to see what is happening at each step. If `r2` is relevant to the binning, you need to explain how it is useful; if not, it may need to be removed and re-joined later.

Comment: That's the part I don't understand. Because I would need to double nest the results. If I nest by r2 `nest(df2, r2, .key = "r2")` I still need to nest by snp `nest(df2, snp, .key = "snp")` which will create the categories. If I use the code you sent and try to nest it with the addition in the df2 data frame: `df %>% left_join(nest(df2, snp, .key = "snp"), by = c("y" = "sca"))` it's keeping the r2 values separate. But I would like to compute the mean at the same time. So I don't know how to nest things twice...

Comment: You've changed the problem, and therefore changed your expected output. It isn't clear to me how you would do that exactly ...

Comment: OK! Here is a new question instead just to clarify: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752268/how-to-compute-the-mean-in-different-categories-using-left-join-and-nest-in-r

Answer (score 2):

In base R:

```
data.frame(table(cat=cut(df2$snp, seq(0,400,100)),sca=df2$sca))

#       cat   sca Freq
#1   (0,100] sca1    4
#2 (100,200] sca1    0
#3 (200,300] sca1    0
#4 (300,400] sca1    0
#5   (0,100] sca2    4
#6 (100,200] sca2    0
#7 (200,300] sca2    0
#8 (300,400] sca2    1
```