# How to compute the mean in different categories using left_join and nest in R?

Tags: r, left-join, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to compute the mean values for binned data using `left_join` and `nest`.

```
bin.size = 100
```

First dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(x =c(300,400), 
                y = c("sca1","sca2"))
    x    y
1 300 sca1
2 400 sca2
```

Second dataframe:

```
df2 = data.frame(snp = c(1,2,10,100,1,2,14,16,399), 
                 sca = c("sca1","sca1","sca1","sca1","sca2","sca2","sca2","sca2","sca2"))

      snp   r2  sca
1   1 0.70 sca1
2   2 0.80 sca1
3  10 0.70 sca1
4 100 0.10 sca1
5   1 0.90 sca2
6   2 0.98 sca2
7  14 0.80 sca2
8  16 0.80 sca2
9 399 0.01 sca2
```

Code from @r2evans:

```
output_bin_LD = df %>%
  left_join(nest(df2, snp, .key = "snp"), by = c("y" = "sca")) %>%
  mutate(
    cuts = map(x, ~ seq(0, ., by = bin.size)),
    tbls = pmap(
      .l = list(snp, cuts),
      .f = function(xx, breaks) {
        z <- table(cut(xx$snp, breaks))
        data_frame(cut = names(z), count = z)
      }
    )
  ) %>%
  select(y, tbls) %>%
  unnest()
```

This [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731684/how-to-cut-a-number-in-different-bin-and-expand-the-data-frame-with-the-new-bins/41732454?noredirect=1#comment70690878_41732454) up is doing this:

```
     y       cut count
1 sca1   (0,100]     4
2 sca1 (100,200]     0
3 sca1 (200,300]     0
4 sca2   (0,100]     4
5 sca2 (100,200]     0
6 sca2 (200,300]     0
7 sca2 (300,400]     1
```

The end goal would be to have

```
     y       cut count  mean
1 sca1   (0,100]     4 0.575
2 sca1 (100,200]     0     0
3 sca1 (200,300]     0     0
4 sca2   (0,100]     4  0.87
5 sca2 (100,200]     0     0
6 sca2 (200,300]     0     0
7 sca2 (300,400]     1   399
```

So far I've tried this:

```
df %>%
  left_join(nest(df2, snp, r2, .key = "snp"), 
            by = c("y" = "sca")) %>%
  mutate(
    cuts = map(x, ~ seq(0, ., by = 100)),
    tbls = pmap(
      .l = list(snp, cuts),
      .f = function(xx, breaks) {
        z <- table(cut(xx$snp, breaks))
        a <- mean(cut(xx$r2, breaks))
        data_frame(cut = names(z), count = z, mean = a)
      } # .f 
    ) # closing pmap
  ) %>% # mutate
  select(y, tbls) %>%
  unnest()
```

But it outputs me `NA`s and a warning message:

```
     y       cut count mean
1 sca1   (0,100]     4   NA
2 sca1 (100,200]     0   NA
3 sca1 (200,300]     0   NA
4 sca2   (0,100]     4   NA
5 sca2 (100,200]     0   NA
6 sca2 (200,300]     0   NA
7 sca2 (300,400]     1   NA
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(cut(xx$r2, breaks)) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(cut(xx$r2, breaks)) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

How should I fix this? Do I need to double nest the table?

Comment: The Q has not much to do with `tidyr` and I'm not sure of `dplyr` here either. It's just a carry-over from the linked Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about *your* approach, but here's a slightly straightforward approach.. using `data.table` package, if you're interested. You will need the latest version (currently 1.10.0) for this to work (since it's a new feature).

```
require(data.table) ## v1.9.8+
and <- b[a, on=.(sca=y, snp>start, snp<=end),       ## 1
         .(count=.N, mean=mean(r2, na.rm=TRUE)),    ## 2
         by=.EACHI]                                 ## 3
```

1. For each row in `a`, find matching row indices in `b` while matching on the condition provided to `on` argument.
2. `length(matching row indices)` == `.N` gives `count` and `mean()` gives the mean of `r2` for those matching indices.
3. The expression in `(2)` is run for each row in `a`.

where, `a` is:

```
require(data.table) ## v1.9.8+
a <- setDT(df)[, .(start=seq(0, x-1, by=bin.size), 
                   end=seq(bin.size, x, by=bin.size)), 
                 by=y]

b <- fread("snp   r2  sca
      1 0.70 sca1
      2 0.80 sca1
     10 0.70 sca1
    100 0.10 sca1
      1 0.90 sca2
      2 0.98 sca2
     14 0.80 sca2
     16 0.80 sca2
    399 0.01 sca2")
```

Comment: Just for the record, I had version 1.9.6. Now I have 1.10.0. And I have this error: `Error in `[.data.table`(b, a, on = .(sca = y, snp > start, snp <= end),: could not find function "."`

Comment: remove the package first and reinstall it.. See the install instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).. See the part about reverting to `CRAN` version.

Comment: Just for info, is there a way to make the b object equal to df2? If I'm using b = df2 and run your code, it's not working...

Comment: I suggest having a look at the pdf/video (red icons on top right each) linked on the [homepage](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) to get started with data.tables.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tidyverse option that's heavier on dplyr than purrr, which makes it somewhat more readable:

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>% group_by(sca, cut = cut(snp, seq(0, max(df$x), bin.size))) %>%   
    summarise(count = n(),    # For each group, count rows
              mean = mean(r2)) %>%    # and calculate mean
    # Add rows for every level of the cuts. Fill new rows with zeros.
    complete(cut, fill = list(count = 0L, mean = 0)) %>% 
    separate(cut, c('from', 'to'), sep = ',') %>%    # Split cut into two numbers
    mutate_at(vars(from:to), parse_number) %>%    # Extract numbers from strings
    left_join(df, c(sca = 'y')) %>%    # Join to get x value for each group
    filter(to <= x)    # Subset to rows where the max cut is within the range.

#> Source: local data frame [7 x 6]
#> Groups: sca [2]
#> 
#>     sca  from    to count  mean     x
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  sca1     0   100     4 0.575   300
#> 2  sca1   100   200     0 0.000   300
#> 3  sca1   200   300     0 0.000   300
#> 4  sca2     0   100     4 0.870   400
#> 5  sca2   100   200     0 0.000   400
#> 6  sca2   200   300     0 0.000   400
#> 7  sca2   300   400     1 0.010   400
```

You can actually avoid the join and messing with the cuts with a little regex and subsetting:

```
df2 %>% group_by(sca, cut = cut(snp, seq(0, max(df$x), bin.size))) %>% 
    summarise(count = n(), 
              mean = mean(r2)) %>% 
    complete(cut, fill = list(count = 0L, mean = 0)) %>% 
    filter(as.integer(gsub('.*,(\\d+).*', '\\1', cut)) <= df$x[unique(sca) == df$y])

#> Source: local data frame [7 x 4]
#> Groups: sca [2]
#> 
#>     sca       cut count  mean
#>   <chr>    <fctr> <int> <dbl>
#> 1  sca1   (0,100]     4 0.575
#> 2  sca1 (100,200]     0 0.000
#> 3  sca1 (200,300]     0 0.000
#> 4  sca2   (0,100]     4 0.870
#> 5  sca2 (100,200]     0 0.000
#> 6  sca2 (200,300]     0 0.000
#> 7  sca2 (300,400]     1 0.010
```

---

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(300, 400), y = c("sca1", "sca2")), .Names = c("x", 
    "y"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(snp = c(1L, 2L, 10L, 100L, 1L, 2L, 14L, 16L, 399L
    ), r2 = c(0.7, 0.8, 0.7, 0.1, 0.9, 0.98, 0.8, 0.8, 0.01), sca = c("sca1", 
    "sca1", "sca1", "sca1", "sca2", "sca2", "sca2", "sca2", "sca2"
    )), .Names = c("snp", "r2", "sca"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```